# Convert part of string to upper (or lower) case

Tags: r, string, uppercase, lowercase

I have a vector with sample locations, here's a sample:

```
test <- c("Aa, Heeswijk T1", "Aa, Heeswijk t1", 
          "Aa, Middelrode t2", "Aa, Middelrode p1",
          "Aa, Heeswijk t1a", "Aa, Heeswijk t3b",
          "Aa, test1 T1", "Aa, test2 t1")
```

These strings are made out of a location name ("Aa, Heeswijk"), a route code ("T1", "p2", "t3") and sometimes a subroute ("a" or "b"). Unfortunately the route codes (t1, t2, p1, t1a) are sometimes in upper and sometimes in lower case. **I want to have all the route codes in UPPER case, leaving the name and subroute unchanged**. My expected outcome is:

```
"Aa, Heeswijk T1", "Aa, Heeswijk T1", 
"Aa, Middelrode T2", "Meander Assendelft P1",
"Aa, Heeswijk T1a", "Aa, Heeswijk T3b"
"Aa, test1 T1", "Aa, test2 T1"
```

I have looked at `toupper()` but that changes to whole string. I could also use gsub:

```
gsub("t1","T1", test)
gsub("t2","T2", test)
#etc.
```

But there must be a better R-ish way?!
Note: Route codes are always 2 chars long, have a char and an integer and are preceded by a space. So the char to change to upper is always located at the second or third from last.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use regex lookarounds.  We match and capture a word starting with lower case letter followed by regex lookahead number (`(?=[0-9])`) as a group (using parentheses) and in the replacement we use `\\U` followed by the capture group to convert it to upper case.

```
 sub('\\b([a-z])(?=[0-9])', '\\U\\1', test, perl=TRUE)
 #[1] "Aa, Heeswijk T1"       "Aa, Heeswijk T1"       "Aa, Middelrode T2"    
 #[4] "Meander Assendelft P1" "Aa, Heeswijk T1a"      "Aa, Heeswijk T3b"
```

Or without using the lookarounds, we can do this with two capture groups.

```
 sub('\\b([a-z])([0-9])', '\\U\\1\\2', test, perl=TRUE)
```

#### Update

Testing with the updated 'test' from the OP's post

```
sub('\\b([a-z])(?=[0-9])', '\\U\\1', test, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "Aa, Heeswijk T1"   "Aa, Heeswijk T1"   "Aa, Middelrode T2"
#[4] "Aa, Middelrode P1" "Aa, Heeswijk T1a"  "Aa, Heeswijk T3b" 
#[7] "Aa, test1 T1"      "Aa, test2 T1"
```

Comment: That works all right. I note however that you are using the integer to find the position, not the position in the string (second or third but last). That works in this example, because there are no integers in the names. I must check if my database has no occurences of integers in names either.

Comment: @RHA Can you provide a different example to test with other cases.

Comment: I've added "Aa, test1 T1" and "Aa, test2 t1" to the example. You solution changes that to "tesT1 T1".

Comment: It does! What does that \\b do?!

Comment: @RHA It is a word boundary so that lower case letters in the middle of a word followed by number will not get changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to avoid regex (which I wouldn't recommend doing), you can practice some R gymnastics:

```
df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(test, " ")), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Now you have everything split into colums of a dataframe:

```
> df
   X1         X2  X3
1 Aa,   Heeswijk  T1
2 Aa,   Heeswijk  t1
3 Aa, Middelrode  t2
4 Aa, Middelrode  p1
5 Aa,   Heeswijk t1a
6 Aa,   Heeswijk t3b
7 Aa,      test1  T1
8 Aa,      test2  t1
```

Next:

```
df[, 3]  <- paste(toupper(substr(df[, 3], 1, 2)), substr(df[, 3], 3, nchar(df[, 3])), sep="")
```

will do your uppercasing:

```
> df
   X1         X2  X3
1 Aa,   Heeswijk  T1
2 Aa,   Heeswijk  T1
3 Aa, Middelrode  T2
4 Aa, Middelrode  P1
5 Aa,   Heeswijk T1a
6 Aa,   Heeswijk T3b
7 Aa,      test1  T1
8 Aa,      test2  T1
```

Lastly, collapse it all back down:

```
ans <- apply(df, 1, paste, collapse=" ")
ans
```

...which gives you:

```
> ans
[1] "Aa, Heeswijk T1"   "Aa, Heeswijk T1"   "Aa, Middelrode T2" "Aa, Middelrode P1" "Aa, Heeswijk T1a"  "Aa, Heeswijk T3b"  "Aa, test1 T1"     
[8] "Aa, test2 T1"
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I am now pretty sure I don't want to avoid regex as I'm not the gymnastic type :-D

Comment: It is only three lines though!